# How many NAND flash chips (measured in Gb) are required for a 32GB USB drive? What is the economic relationship between the two?

Tags: memory, flash, non-volatile-memory

NAND Flash Contract Price http://www.insye.com/dp/NANDFlashContractPrice.aspx

Context, I am purchasing about 200k USB drives. I sent it out to competitive bid but I want greater insight into the BOM cost for these manufacturers. 200k units isn't enough to demand they give disaggregated pricing (big OEM orders are 1M+ units). I just did a straight transfer from Gb to GB (divide by 8). Thus, a USB 32 GB TLC-based drive would require 8 32 Gb TLC chips at $2.24 a piece, or ~$18. The problem is that I have quotes for the same USB drive from a major manufacturer for ~$10, and this includes the PCB board, the controller, the case, silkscreened logos, plus their markup. Is the spot price for NAND flash simply incorrect (error on site?) or is my math wrong?

Comment: They will use a single memory IC (or less :-) ).

Comment: Looking at the same listing shows the 128Gbit part at a low price of $4.20 giving your memory for $8.40, leaving $1.60 for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Probably 1 256Gbit MLC part with built in controller plus pcb, case and assembly.   Also the public spot price doesn't necessarily equal the most up to date accurate info they will show you if you pay to see their pricing.   Surprised at that volume you can't demand a costed bom.